# How to use the for loop to cut and paste in Cygwin?

Tags: loops, for-loop, cygwin, paste, cut

I'm trying to run the for loop included below to cut and paste but it fails to recognize my files here. I was able to use the for loop to run a perl command using similar files and it had worked without any glitches then.

```
for i in {100..1600..100}; do
cut -c 1-26110 chr1a1_$i.out.long >> chr1a1_$i_a.out.long
cut -c 1001-27110 chr1a2_$i.out.long >> chr1a2_$i_a.out.long
paste -d '' chr1a1_$i_a.out.long chr1a2_$i_a.out.long >> chr1a1_$i_b.out.long
done
```

Thanks.

Comment: have u google on the same stuff under unix/linux? after all cygwin is just en emulator for *nix in windows.

Comment: Yes, the google searches included unix/linux results. And I wrote the command based on a couple of them but I can't figure out what I am missing here. I tried including the pipe symbol after the cut command but before the file name, it then thinks my file is the command and returns the error "-bash: chr1a1_100.out.long: command not found".